SearchBar de Compose no me deja introducir ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú
Estoy usando el componente SearchBar de Compose (ExperimentalMaterial3Api), pero no me deja poner caracteres especiales españoles (ñ, á, é, í, ó, ú, etc.). Cuando los intento introducir en el input simplemente los ignora. No sé si hay algo que me falta o si es un problema de que el componente está en experimental. No he encontrado ninguna explicación online. Hay alguna forma de solucionarlo?
Esta es la implementación que he probado:
var query by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

SearchBar(
    query = query,
    onQueryChange = {query = it},
    onSearch = {},
    active = true,
    onActiveChange = {}
) {

}


Estás usando un código obsoleto de SearchBar, en la última versión debes pasar un inputField como parámetro. Por favor, revisa el ejemplo de SearchBarSample en este enlace. Con ese código, admite los acentos sin problema ninguno, como podrás ver en la captura.

Estás usando un código obsoleto de SearchBar, en la última versión debes pasar un inputField como parámetro.
Por ejemplo:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchBarSample() {
    var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var expanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .semantics { isTraversalGroup = true }) {
        SearchBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
                .semantics { traversalIndex = 0f },
            inputField = {
                SearchBarDefaults.InputField(
                    query = text,
                    onQueryChange = { text = it },
                    onSearch = { expanded = false },
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onExpandedChange = { expanded = it },
                    placeholder = { Text("Escriba el texto") },
                    leadingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = null) },
                    trailingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.MoreVert, contentDescription = null) },
                )
            },
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = { expanded = it },
        ) {
            Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
                repeat(4) { idx ->
                    val resultText = "Suggestion $idx"
                    ListItem(
                        headlineContent = { Text(resultText) },
                        supportingContent = { Text("Additional info") },
                        leadingContent = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Star, contentDescription = null) },
                        colors = ListItemDefaults.colors(containerColor = Color.Transparent),
                        modifier =
                        Modifier
                            .clickable {
                                text = resultText
                                expanded = false
                            }
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, top = 72.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            modifier = Modifier.semantics { traversalIndex = 1f },
        ) {
            val list = List(100) { "Text $it" }
            items(count = list.size) {
                Text(
                    text = list[it],
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Como podrás ver en la imagen, admite acentos sin problema ninguno:

Para más detalles, puedes consultar este enlace.

Muchas gracias, he actualizado dependencias y ahora sí me sale la SearchBar correcta.
